# Dynamically allocate elements in tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a simple question since I did not find it online.

Is it safe to modify the elements in a tuple if I pass it by reference like this, I put it like that to emulate what I do.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename... Args>
struct S {
  tuple<Args...> tup;             //my tuple to hold data types but empty initially

  auto& args() { return tup; }    //method to access my tuple
};


// some function that modifies my tuple
void foo(auto& tup) {
  std::get<0>(tup).resize(1000);
  std::get<1>(tup)[76] = 654;
  std::get<1>(tup)[453] = 6;
}

int main() {
  S<vector<int>, map<int, int>> s;     // my object

  foo(s.args());

  printf("vecSize = %d\n", std::get<0>(s.args()).size());
  printf("mapSize = %d\n", std::get<1>(s.args()).size());

  return 0;
}
```

The previous piece of code works well, but I am not entirely sure if the memory, allocated for this tuple and its elements, won't be corrupted eventually when implementing too many dynamic allocations, assuming that the whole memory does not reach the limit.

Comment: Not really sure what you're worried about. Passing around references to objects is perfectly normal. If that objects is a tuple, a map, a vector or any combination of those things doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S`, it's member tuple, and *its* members (vector+map) exist as `s` for the lifetime of the `main` method.  You pass a reference to the tuple to the function `foo` which modifies those fully-alive members safely.  This is all 100% valid and safe. I do not see any undefined behavior, leaks, or dangling references anywhere.